# mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Unable to receive - Connection refused in Centos 7 client

Tags: centos, centos7, nfs

I am trying to connect to a nfs server. where i seeing the below issue.

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon May 11 19:27:01 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=IP'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Unable to receive - Connection refused
```

1. nfs-utils is installed and running in the client.
2. rpcbind is running in the client machine
3. Ports 111, 2049 and 892 are opened to the NFS server.

However i am not sure if i am missing anything to resolve this issue.

Comment: what about rpcbind on server?

Comment: Doesn't seem to have an issue on the server side. as i am able to mount the share in the same segment machines.

Comment: In your example, it's nfsv3. Down other host use v3 as well? (and check firewall on the client host)

Comment: yes v3.. On client side, no firewall no iptables, no selinux enabled... On the firewall, we have temporarily enabled any -any just for testing purpose but no luck.

Comment: Can you update post with result of `rpcinfo -l <nfsserver> 100003 3`

Comment: Error is "rpcinfo: can't contact rpcbind: : RPC: Timed out"

Comment: Strongly believe some prob in the network. But cant justify it.. Somebody help pls

Comment: I will start with simple  network test, like: 'nc -v -z <nfsserver> 111' and 'nc -v -z -u <nfsserver> 111' and to port 2049. And then with traceroute. Looks like a local or router firewall.

Comment: I have the same problem on SLES, but `rpcinfo -l 10.0.0.2 100003 3` shows nfs tcp and udp services.